# Convert WCHAR[260] to std::string

Tags: c++, windows, string, wchar

I have gotten a WCHAR[MAX_PATH] from (PROCESSENTRY32) pe32.szExeFile on Windows.  The following do not work:

```
std::string s;
s = pe32.szExeFile; // compile error. cast (const char*) doesnt work either
```

and

```
std::string s;
char DefChar = ' ';
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,pe32.szExeFile,-1, ch,260,&DefChar, NULL);
s = pe32.szExeFile;
```

Comment: Do you really need it as a `std::string`? It should convert directly to a `std::wstring`, as in `std::wstring s(pe32.szExeFile);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `WideCharToMultiByte` looks correct, provided `ch` is a
sufficiently large buffer.  After than, however, you want to assign the
buffer (`ch`) to the string (or use it to construct a string), not
`pe32.szExeFile`.

Answer (score 3):

For your first example you can just do:

```
std::wstring s(pe32.szExeFile);
```

and for second:

```
char DefChar = ' ';
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP,0,pe32.szExeFile,-1, ch,260,&DefChar, NULL);
std::wstring s(pe32.szExeFile);
```

as `std::wstring` has a `char*` ctor

Comment: Neither work same error. error: C2664: 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::basic_string(std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::_Has_debug_it)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'WCHAR [260]' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>

Comment: sorry should've used wstring version, should compile now

Comment: @user1334943 does it work with `std::wstring s(&pe32.szExeFile)`?

Answer (score 2):

There are convenient [conversion classes from ATL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3%28v=vs.100%29.aspx); you may want to use some of them, e.g.:

```
std::string s( CW2A(pe32.szExeFile) );
```

Note however that a conversion from Unicode UTF-16 to ANSI can be *lossy*. If you wan't a non-lossy conversion, you could **convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8**, and store UTF-8 inside `std::string`.

If you don't want to use ATL, there are some convenient freely available C++ wrappers around raw Win32 `WideCharToMultiByte` to [convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 using STL strings](https://msmvps.com/blogs/gdicanio/archive/2011/02/04/conversion-between-unicode-utf-8-and-utf-16-with-stl-strings.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifndef __STRINGCAST_H__
#define __STRINGCAST_H__

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <cwchar>
#include <cassert>

template<typename Td>
Td string_cast(const wchar_t* pSource, unsigned int codePage = CP_ACP);

#endif // __STRINGCAST_H__

template<>
std::string string_cast( const wchar_t* pSource, unsigned int codePage )
{
    assert(pSource != 0);
    size_t sourceLength = std::wcslen(pSource);
    if(sourceLength > 0)
    {
        int length = ::WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, pSource, sourceLength, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
        if(length == 0)
            return std::string();

        std::vector<char> buffer( length );
        ::WideCharToMultiByte(codePage, 0, pSource, sourceLength, &buffer[0], length, NULL, NULL);

        return std::string(buffer.begin(), buffer.end());
    }
    else
        return std::string();

}
```

and use this template as followed

```
PWSTR CurWorkDir;
std::string CurWorkLogFile;

CurWorkDir = new WCHAR[length];

CurWorkLogFile = string_cast<std::string>(CurWorkDir);

....


delete [] CurWorkDir;
```